# /etc/hosts file doesnt forward to localhost for subdomain begins with www

Tags: domain-name-system, localhost, hosts-file

On my desktop I use  /etc/hosts file like as below for developing purpose

```
127.0.0.1   a.example.com
127.0.0.1   www.a.example.com
127.0.0.1   adsense.a.example.com
127.0.0.1   foto.a.example.com
```

They all work except www.a.example.com it doesn't forward to localhost.
Could you explain why? and any workaround?

I use Ubuntu 10.10. Thanks

Comment: OP requested it be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean with "They work"? Where? In a browser? On the console?

What is the output of

```
host www.a.example.com
```

or

```
dig www.a.example.com
```

on the console?

Comment: when I ping it doesnt route to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Where to then? Which IP address? Or what error do you get?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a syntax error in /etc/hosts? ping should work!

Comment: I rewrote and it worked. Although I havent seen any difference it worked. probably I wrote wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Some theories:

1. The www.a.example.com record is seperated by tabs as opposes to spaces for the rest, or visa-versa. In theory, the host file should accept either tabs or spaces, but ubuntu might be picky.
2. Something else in your host file is taking precedence over www.a.example.com. Is there an entry for *.a.example.com
3. Does www.a.example.com contain any unicode characters? If you display it with cat, less or more on a terminal doe it look funny?